# Error while installing php extension 'expect'

Tags: php, pecl, expect

I got some serious error while installing expect extension in PHP.

I ran `sudo pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/expect-0.3.1`

I got error like this while running make,

```
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootvXp7LZ/expect-0.3.1/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/expect -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootvXp7LZ/expect-0.3.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootvXp7LZ/expect-0.3.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/expect -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/expect/expect.c -o expect.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/expect -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootvXp7LZ/expect-0.3.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootvXp7LZ/expect-0.3.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/expect -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/expect/expect.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/expect.o
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/expect/expect.c:21:0:
/tmp/pear/temp/expect/php_expect.h:33:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [expect.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Please advice me as I am a very beginner in PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Which OS/Distro have you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

You should install `expect-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install expect-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install tcl-dev

```
# apt-get install tcl-dev
```

It's my fault, the tcl.h is provided in tcl8.4-dev/tcl8.5-dev

```
tcl8.4-dev: /usr/include/tcl8.4/tcl.h
tcl8.5-dev: /usr/include/tcl8.5/tcl.h
```

You can find which package contain tcl.h with apt-file

```
# apt-file search tcl.h
```

Comment: Still I am getting the same error !